# requestPictureInPicture not working on iOS PWA

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, html5-video, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to trigger Pictuer-in-picture (PiP) on a HTML video using the following code:

```
await videoElement.requestPictureInPicture().catch((error) => 
    alert(`PiP failed, ${error}`);
);
```

This works fine in Safari, but when you use 'Add to home screen' with `"display": "standalone"` set in the manifest, this code returns an error saying picture in picture is unsupported.
Additionally the built-in PiP control is missing from the video player.

Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix it? I assumed the PWA/standalone version uses the same browser/js engine behind the scenes as regular Safari on the device, but it looks like it may be different?

Comment: Same question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As of March 2021:**

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to trigger PiP mode in PWAs (yet).
The API is missing in standalone mode.

I did some research and tried to find some workarounds.

The only thing that somehow works is to force the user to load the page containing the video in Safari. In order for this to work you have to play with the scope param inside your manifest.

1. Put your PWA in a subfolder like `/pwa` and set `"scope": "/pwa"`
2. Put your Video pages in another subfolder like `/videos`

Everytime a user navigates to a video page, the scope of your PWA will be left. As soon as this happens, your PWA will leave the fullscreen mode and safari will render its top and bottoms bars.
Inside the bottom bar will be a small safari icon. The user must click it. Safari will open, PiP will be available.

To make the process a little bit smoother you can render a custom PiP button as video control. If the user clicks it, you check if your app is running in standalone mode by checking `window.navigator.standalone`. If it's `false`, just request PiP.

Otherwise, you navigate out of your PWAs scope. Use the history API (`history.pushState`) to change the location without reloading the page. You can add a query param like `autopip=true`. Finally, you show an overlay describing that the user should click the safari button in the bottom right corner.
Safari will open the page you pushed to the history. In Safari, check if the query param `autopip=true` is set and use JS to request PiP after video has loaded.

**The big gotcha:** There is no way to redirect the user back to your PWA.